# How to convert 2D array into Vector

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, vector, fstream

> ```
> For example: [ticket.txt] 
>  (Number)  (Amount)
>   09         10 
>   13         15 
>   25         21
> ```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int rowNumber = 0;
    ifstream inFile, inFile2;
    string line;
    inFile.open("Ticket.txt"); //open File
    inFile2.open("Ticket.txt");
    if (inFile.fail()) // If file cannot open, the code will end
    {
        cout << "Fail to open the file" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    while (getline(inFile2, line)) //  get whole lines and two valid numbers(numbers and amounts)
        ++rowNumber;
    cout << "Number of lines in text file: " << rowNumber << "\n";


    int myArray[rowNumber][2]; //declare 2d array
        for(int i = 0; i < rowNumber; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                inFile >> myArray[i][j];
}
```

My code is running well, but I want to convert a 2d array into vector. While reading file by arrays has a fixed size, so vector is a good solution to solve this problem.

Comment: *My code is running well, but I want to convert a 2d array into vector.* -- If that's the question, then you don't need to give details on ticket wins and losses.  Just write a simple main program that takes a 2D array and creates a vector of vectors.

Comment: Because most of my code is using arrays, I'm trying to convert them to a vector, but it seems not working well. I have never used vector before, so it's just new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Given your file structure you can read lines into a temporary vector and then insert it into a vector of vectors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
int main(){
    std::ifstream myfile("Tickets.txt");
    std::vector<int> temprow(2);
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix{};
    int rowcount = 0;
    while (myfile >> temprow[0] >> temprow[1]){
        matrix.push_back(temprow);
        rowcount++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            std::cout << matrix[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This assumes your 2D array is N * 2.